# Symfony migration "The table with name "[name]" already exists

Tags: database, symfony, sql-update, database-migration, symfony6

I am currrently working on a symfony porfolio project and during the course of the project I had to reinstall xampp. As I didn't save my database I lost it. I tried to recreate it with this commands:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
php bin/console make:migration
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

But I get this error

```
The table with name "portfolio.project_tag" already exists.
```

To give you context my entities are 'Project', 'Tag' and 'Category'. Project and Tag have a ManyToMany relation as each Project can have many Tags and each tag can have many projects. Project and Categorie also have a OneToMany relationship bacause each project is in a category and each categorie can have multiple projects.
I also have 'User' entity to enter my admin dashboard.

I tried deleting all of linked entities (Project, Category and Tag) but it only made things worse.
I don't understand how the table can already exist since I had no database in the first place.

Plus, I had no problem with my tables before I accidentally suppressed my database like an idiot.

Tell me if you need more detail, thanks for your help.

I tried to suppress all of the lines related to portfolio.project_tag table in my migration file but it didn't work either

Comment: Did you tr deleting and recreating DB?

Comment: Yes, I tried multiple times to delete it then recreating it with 'php bin/console doctrine:database:create' 
In the end I restarted the entire project since I was not that advanced on it but someone has an answer I think it could still be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had two different ManyToMany relationships, which serve different purposes, between the same two entities (Program and Participant) and used make:entity to create them. However, the command line tool doesn't ask you for a name for the join table, so when you attempt to update the schema it uses uses the default name for both, which in this case is `participant_program`.

In order to resolve this, explicitly name the join table for the ManyToMany, e.g.,

- `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Program", inversedBy="enrolled_participants")`
- `@ORM\JoinTable( name="enrolled_programs", joinColumns={`
- `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="participant_id", referencedColumnName="id") }, inverseJoinColumns={`
- `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="program_id", referencedColumnName="id") } )`

`private $enrolled_programs;`